# WP conditional statement for multiple categories

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

**Here is my goal:**
Specifically on a tag/archive page: I would like to show a different sidebar for each category that is displayed on the page.

What I have done now:
I have three categories, 'Paintings', 'Photography', and 'Objects'. 
When a tag page is displayed, I want to check if it has any posts from the category 'Paintings' and if so, I would like it to display the dynamic_sidebar 'paintings-sidebar'.. Photography -> photography_sidebar and Objects -> object_sidebar.

This part I have accomplished.

My issue comes when a tag/archive page contains posts from multiple categories. For example, posts from category 'Paintings' and posts from category'Photography'. In which case I would like to have 'paintings_sidebar' and 'photography_sidebar' show up.

As it is now, only the sidebar for the most recent post's category is displayed in the sidebar.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Here is my little bit of code:

```
if (is_archive()) {
  if (in_category( 'paintings' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'paintings-sidebar' ); 
  }     
  if (in_category( 'photography' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'photography-sidebar' ); 
  } 
  if (in_category( 'objects' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'objects-sidebar' ); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use elseif:

```
if (is_archive()) {
  if (in_category( 'paintings' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'paintings-sidebar' ); 
  }     
  elseif (in_category( 'photography' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'photography-sidebar' ); 
  } 
  elseif (in_category( 'objects' )) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'objects-sidebar' ); 
  }
```